# Корректна ли в русском языке конструкция "должна была быть упомянута"?

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые

Подскажите, пожалуйста, является ли корректной конструкция с "должна была быть упомянута" или же корректнее всё-таки "должна была упоминаться", и, если первый вариант корректен, то какой это тип сказуемого, СИС?

Comment: Корректна это фразчонка.

Comment: Эта фраза только корректная, но и более частотная. Но ведь вторая фразчонка грамматически тоже корректна. Так почему чаще употребляется первая, как вы думаете?

Comment: @Sharon
Вообще я взял эту фразу из книги, переведённой на русский язык с немецкого языка, и мне вспомнилось, что в английском языке вроде бы как есть конструкции с should have has, что натолкнуло меня на мысль о возможной некорректности подобного построения предложений в русском языке. Лично мне больше нравится вариант с возвратным глаголом.

Comment: Тогда мое объяснение как раз для вас. Повторение глаголов не кажется нам корректным, но в деловом стиле используется именно этот вариант. Всем нашим участникам он тоже нравится, Вот я и задумалась о причине.

Comment: @Sharon я благодарен Вам за Ваше разъяснение. При самостоятельном изучении русского языка, с помощью литературы и интернета можно самому разобраться практически в любом вопросе, кроме синтаксиса, так как именно он, как мне кажется, больше всего богат различными точками зрения.

Comment: Вы правы. Синтаксис даже в базовом варианте вызывает много вопросов, но и такого уровня бывает недостаточно. Приходится обращаться к другим источникам. Пунктуация основана на знании синтаксиса, а не только правил. Наши основные темы на форуме – грамматика, пунктуация, стилистика.

Comment: @Sharon подскажите, можно ли иногда задавать Вам вопросы по синтаксису вне этого форума, так как некоторые из них кажутся мне слишком уж примитивными.

Comment: Лучше все-таки на форуме, мы обязательно ответим вам, и  я в том числе. (И знаете, примитивных вопросов не бывает. Иногда на такие вопросы даже труднее ответить, чем на другие.)  И здесь все демократично. Вы можете получить несколько ответов и выбрать для себя подходящую информацию. Можно также уточнить ответ в комментариях. Поэтому задавайте любые вопросы, требование к ним такое. Должна быть понятной формулировка и  желательно краткое пояснение: что вас затруднило в теме. (Это для того, чтобы легче было ответить.)  Если у отвечающих возникли вопросы к вам,  то лучше сразу дать пояснение.

Comment: @Sharon Отлично! В таком случае у меня уже готов новый вопрос.

Comment: Задавайте! Правда, меня днем не будет, но вечером я обязательно уделю ему внимание.

Comment: @Sharon вы знаете, я рад, что на этом сайте познакомился с вами, человеком, который критически и исследовательски подходит к рассматриваемым вопросам. Год назад я был автором вопроса по синтаксису на другом форуме, и самое интересное то, что все специалисты этого форума мне так и не смогли дать правильный ответ на интересующий меня вопрос, хотя некоторые его участники довольно высокого о себе мнения. https://rusforus.ru/viewtopic.php?t=12675 и только сегодня я совершенно случайно прочитал ответ уже на другом сайте на мой вопрос https://proza.ru/2022/10/26/609?ysclid=lnue97urdq99023595

Comment: Спасибо, Иван. Признаться, мне тоже пришлось подумать над этим вопросом. Кроме того, у нас здесь строгие критики, так что думать приходится постоянно))   Но не могу сказать, что все и всегда получается. Неразгаданных вопросов тоже хватает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Вариант с кратким причастием:** *должна была быть упомянута.*

*Статья **должна была быть** упомянута, но ее нет.*

Форма ***"была"*** обозначает **ИРРЕАЛЬНОЕ**  действие, которое не было совершено.  Сравнить: *Статья **должна** быть упомянута, как я думаю.*

Форма ***"быть"*** используется для обозначения **пассивного** залога страдательного причастия (быть упомянута).

**СИС**, грамматическая связка ***"должна была быть"***, именная часть выражена кратким причастием "упомянута".

Эта форма **КОРРЕКТНА** и используется на практике.

**Вопрос о корректности** может возникнуть в связи с **повторением**  глаголов (была быть), но такой повтор имеет **грамматическое обоснование.**

2. **Вариант с возвратным глаголом:** *статья должна была упоминаться.*

*Статья **должна была** упоминаться, но не упоминается.*

Форма ***"была"*** обозначает ирреальное действие, которое не было совершено. Сравнить: *Статья **должна** упоминаться, как я думаю.*

**СГС**, грамматическая связка ***"должна была"***, основной глагол "упоминаться".

В данном случае **повторения глаголов нет.**

Comment: «_Эту форму нежелательна в данном случае из-за наличие повторяющихся глаголов (была быть)_» === И всё же **чаще** (по сравнению с той, что Вы назвали предпочтительной) используется на письме именно эта форма.

Comment: Канцелярия, там свои шаблоны. Нужно было провести грамматический анализ, он проведен. Надеюсь, что автор учтет ваше замечание.

Comment: Sharon: «_Надеюсь, что автор учтет ваше замечание._» === По-моему, Вы тоже учли… 

Comment: Я всегда стараюсь улучшить свой ответ)

Answer (score 1):

Грамматически все корректно, можно до бесконечности осложнять сказуемые (
Я стала начинать становиться быть взрослой). Вот [тут](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/705-16_oslozhnennye_tipy_sostavnyh_skazuemyh.html) стандартные примеры расписаны. Ваш случай фактически описывается в следующем абзаце:

> Должен стать врачом – осложнённое составное именное сказуемое. Именная
> часть (врачом) выражена существительным в творительном падеже;
> полузнаменательная связка стать входит в состав составного глагольного
> сказуемого, в котором основная часть выражена инфинитивом стать;
> вспомогательная часть должен имеет модальное значение и выражена
> составным именным сказуемым. В нём именная часть должен выражена
> кратким прилагательным; нулевая связка указывает на настоящее время
> изъявительного наклонения.

```
Я была должна стать врачом // Осложнённое СИС = составное именное микросказуемое + связка-инфинитив + именная часть СИС
Я была должна быть врачом     // аналогично
Я была должна быть упомянута  // аналогично
```

> Осложнённое СИС = составное именное микросказуемое + связка-инфинитив + именная часть СИС