# В чем отличие двух грамматических форм: должна упоминаться и должна быть упомянута?

Tags: синтаксис, стилистика, причастия

В одном случае мы используем  **возвратный** глагол, а в другом — **краткое страдательное** причастие. Чем **отличаются** эти варианты по стилю и области применения в общем случае?

Данная конструкция обсуждалась  **[в этой теме.](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475599/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0)**

**В деловом стиле** обычно используется  форма  краткого причастия,  но почему именно так?  Ведь глагольный вариант короче и понятнее.  Можно ли найти **обоснование** в учебных материалах?

Также интересно ваше мнение. Это особенность делового стиля — сделать сообщение **менее понятным**  для пользователей?))

Или здесь **другая философия?**

Спасибо.